# What is the language Ionic 2 is built on

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

What programming language is behind ionic 2, on github i can only see css classes for tags of ionic 2 not the actual code of tag, where exactly I can find this, the implementation of tags of ionic 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic2 is written using TypeScript and Sass. It also leverages elements (Component, Directive, ...) and mechanisms provided by Angular2.

The source code of the framework can be reached in Github: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/tree/2.0/ionic.

If you look for the source code of components, you could have a look at the `components` folder.

For example for tabs, here is the corresponding TypeScript source code:

- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/2.0/ionic/components/tabs/tabs.ts
- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/2.0/ionic/components/tabs/tab.ts
- ...

And the SASS one:

- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/2.0/ionic/components/tabs/tabs.scss
- ...

Comment: What about directives for rendering ionic2 tags, where I can find these libraries

Comment: I can't see components for this. I think that you could leverage an existing one (according to your needs) and add some CSS classes to customize it to look like a tag ;-)

Comment: btw what makes tags to render

Comment: I need your assistance here ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129890/how-to-import-youtube-iframe-api-in-ionic2-page

Comment: I need your assistance here @Thierry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133215/the-target-origin-provided-does-not-match-the-recipient-windows-origin-adio-is

Answer (score 1):

Ionic 2 is built using Typescript (same as Angular 2) and Sass.  We have found that Typescript is really great for open-source development since the compiler and static types eliminate an entire class of potential issues.

Ionic 2 will support traditional 'desktop' web, mobile web/progressive web apps, hybrid apps like Ionic 2, and even hybrid 'desktop' apps via Electron.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic runs within [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) (PhoneGap). Ionic is a combination of javascript, html and css files written for you, so that you don't have to write them yourself and concentrate on your application.

So, basically you want to learn in **what programming language Cordova** has been written? As you [can see on GitHub](https://github.com/apache?query=cordova), it uses different languages for different platforms. Mostly Objective-C for iOS, Java for Android, etc.

Comment: Actually I need to use ionic 2 component else where other than within Ionic framework for example in Angular2, so the component of Ionic should render in angular as if they were in Ionic framework itself

Comment: @blackhawk, why not just use Ionic 2, then, since Ionic is components + angular + other great stuff too.